# If $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}(\omega)$, show that $\alpha$ is congruent to either $0, 1$ or $-1$ modulo $1-\omega$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}(\omega)$, show that $\alpha$ is congruent to either $0, 1$ or $-1$ modulo $1-\omega$.

Exercise 1 [page 134](http://books.google.com/books?id=jhAXHuP2y04C&pg=134) in the book 'A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory' of K. Ireland and M. Rosen.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\omega$ being a primitive cubic root of unit?

Comment: and it's $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.

Comment: For the OP: using $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}(\omega)$ is important since the latter suggests a *field*. Specifically when using a field, $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is standard notation for the polynomial ring, and $\mathbb{F}(x)$ is used for the field of "rational functions".

Comment: Try and draw the 2D grid on the plane with the numbers of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ marked with dots. Circle the ones that are congruent to zero modulo $1-\omega$. All will be clear (and this is a useful exercise in its own right)!

Comment: -1 Question ill-posed, without due definitions and without answering back requests for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\: \omega\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\: 0 = \omega^2\!+\!\omega\!+\!1\equiv 3\ $ so $\rm\ \omega\equiv 1,\ 3\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:  m\!+\!n\omega \equiv (m\!+\!n)\:\! mod\ 3\equiv 0,\pm1$